# How to stop overshooting a target position using deltatime and velocity

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics

I'm trying to move a 'train' up and down a track. the track is a list of nodes with x and y coordinates.

The train moves up and down, but sometimes, depending on distance and its velocity, it overshoots a node in 1 deltatime step and starts jumping left and right (or up and down depending on direction) because the node isn't registered as reached.

I tried to build in a threshold. If the node is reached within the threshold amount of pixels it takes the next node as goal. This helps a but of course it keeps happening depending on distance and velocity:

```
if dist <= 5:
        self.currentGoalNode += self.iterateBy
```

I tried to separately calculate the distance traveled in in each millisecond instead of deltatime and check if the goal was reached in each one of those steps, but couldn't get it working and I stopped trying because it seems to lead to a lot of unnecessary code and calculations.

Is there an easy way to fix this or was I on the right "track" and do i need to take the extra code?

My entire code:

```
self.iterateBy = 1
self.floatPosition = self.rect.center

def move (self, dt):

    # calculate distance
    dist = math.hypot(self.path[self.currentGoalNode].x - self.rect.centerx,
                      self.path[self.currentGoalNode].y - self.rect.centery)

    # check if going up or down on path
    if self.currentGoalNode +1 >= self.totalNodes or self.currentGoalNode <= 0:
            self.iterateBy *= -1

    # attempt to eradicate the 'jumping' by making a treshold
    if dist <= 5:
        self.currentGoalNode += self.iterateBy

    diffx, diffy = (self.route[self.currentGoalNode][0] - self.rect.center[0],
                    self.route[self.currentGoalNode][1] - self.rect.center[1])

    angle = math.atan2(diffx, diffy)
    x = (math.sin(angle) * self.velocity) * dt
    y = (math.cos(angle) * self.velocity) * dt

    # keeping track of the position in floats
    self.floatPosition= tuple(map(sum, zip(self.floatPosition, (x,y))))

    # moving the rect and converting to ints
    self.rect.center = self.floatPosition
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're within a 1-delta step from the goal (1dist <= threshold), then don't add `iterator`.  Instead, just set the position to the location of the goal.

Comment: i'm afraid I don't get it? i tried:    if dist <= self.speed * dt: rect.center = nextGoal but it keeps happening?

Comment: That's the general idea.  If this still doesn't work, please update your question with this attempt, including a debug trace of the values involved.  Since you've failed to provide the expected [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I can't check this for you.

Comment: @LennartWijers For an example, you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16294710/142637) answer.