# How to make a image move towards mouse click?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to recreate ballz using pygame for a summative for my ics class. Except i don't know how to make the ball(which is a image) to move to where the user clicks.

This is for pygame, I've tried updating the location, except the ball just flickers in and out in the same spot.

```
def level_2():        
    class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) #construct the parent component
            self.image = pygame.image.load("ball.png").convert_alpha()
            self.image.set_colorkey(self.image.get_at( (0,0) ))
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect() #loads the rect from the image

            #set the position, direction, and speed of the ball
            self.rect.left = 300
            self.rect.top = 600
            self.speed = 4
            self.dir = 0

        def update(self):
            click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
            #Handle the walls by changing direction(s)
            if self.rect.left < 0 or self.rect.right >= screen.get_width():
                self.dir_x *= -1

            if self.rect.top < 0:
                self.dir_y *= -1

    ####CHECK TO SEE IF BALL HITS THE BLOCK AND WILL BOUNCE####
            if pygame.sprite.groupcollide(ball_group, block_group, False, True):
                self.rect.move_ip(self.speed*self.dir_x, self.speed*self.dir_y)

            if self.rect.bottom >= screen.get_height():
                speed = 0
                self.dir_y = 0
                self.dir_x = 0
                self.rect.left = 300
                self.rect.top = 600
                self.rect.move_ip(self.speed*self.dir_x, self.speed*self.dir_y)

            #Move the ball to where the user clicked                 
            if ev.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                (x, y) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                #ASK MS WUN HOW TO DO #
                if self.rect.left != x and self.rect.top != y:
                    #self.rect.move_ip(x, y)
                    self.rect.move_ip(self.speed*self.dir_x, self.speed*self.dir_y)
```

There isn't any error messages, the only thing that happens is either the ball will move in a set direction (if the user clicks on the right side, the ball will move to the right, and if the user clicks on the left, the ball will still move to the right).

Or the ball will just flicker in and out on the same spot

Comment: After the user clicks, does the ball flicker in the new (clicked) spot, or the old spot before the click?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a sprite move to the mouse click position step by step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288905/make-a-sprite-move-to-the-mouse-click-position-step-by-step)

Answer (score 0):

The problem, I think (I can't tell properly without a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) is a misunderstanding of `Rect.move_ip()`. This method translates the `Rect` in a direction, rather than moving towards it. Since you can only click on positive co-ordinates (negative ones are off-screen), this means it will always move down and to the right. If you want to move towards something, the easiest way is something like this:

```py
target_x = 100
target_y = 300
ball_x = 600
ball_y = 200
movedir_x = target_x - ball_x
movedir_y = target_y - ball_y
# Now adjust so that the speed is unaffected by distance to target
length = (movedir_x ** 2 + movedir_y ** 2) ** 0.5
movedir_x *= speed / length
movedir_y *= speed / length
```

and then translate the ball by this `movedir` rather than the ball's position. I think at this point you should probably just use Pygame's [Vector2](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) class. Then the equivalent would just be:

```py
target = pygame.math.Vector2(100, 300)
ball = pygame.math.Vector2(600, 200)
movedir = (target - ball).normalize() * speed
```